# qgis2threejs installation

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis2threejs

I am a beginner in QGIS. I am trying to create 3D models using Qgis2threejs plugin. I installed it but am not able to find the tool. I only see "Qgis2threejs Exporter/Exporter without Preview tool" under Web. 
[image: Qgis2threejs screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You use the exporter to build the 3d model. 
Select Web > Qgis2ThreeJs > Qgis2ThreeJs Exporter.

You can the select data you wish to be displayed on the left hand panel.